# Nginx: (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream wordpress & docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

As many people I have the problem with the following error when I call the website (blog.mydomain.de):

502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.14.2

```
2020/03/14 23:59:08 [error] 7#7: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: $IP, server: blog.mydomain.de, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://192.168.160.5:443/", host: "blog.mydomain.de"
```

So my problem is using WordPress. I also show you the NextCloud config because this works without any problems. I also know that the WordPress nginx config should contain more but I tried to find it if I even get this error with minimal config missing fastcgi and stuff.

```
worker_processes auto;

include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  gzip            on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types      text/plain text/css text/xml
                  application/javascript application/json application/xml application/rss+xml image/svg+xml;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  more_clear_headers 'server';

  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de-0001/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de-0001/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de-0001/chain.pem;
  ssl_dhparam         /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;
  ssl_ciphers         "EECDH-AESGCM:EDH+ESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  add_header          Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
      server_name blog.mydomain.de cloud.mydomain.de;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  # NextCloudPi

  server {
    server_name cloud.mydomain.de;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    client_max_body_size 100G;
        underscores_in_headers on;

    location / {
          proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
          proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 64;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

          add_header Front-End-Https on;
          proxy_pass https://nextcloudpi;
    }
  }

  # NextCloudPi Konfiguration Web-Interface

  server {
    server_name cloud.mydomain.de;

    listen 4443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:4433 ssl http2;

    location / {
      more_clear_headers 'upgrade';
      more_clear_headers 'Strict-Transport-Security';

      proxy_ssl_verify off;
      proxy_pass https://nextcloudpi:4443;

      proxy_pass_header Authorization;

      proxy_set_header 'X-Forwarded-Host' cloud.mydomain.de;
      proxy_set_header 'X-Forwarded-Proto' https;
      proxy_set_header 'X-Forwarded-For' $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header 'X-Forwarded-IP' $remote_addr;
    }
  }

  # WordPress

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name blog.mydomain.de;

      client_max_body_size 200m;
      underscores_in_headers on;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://wordpress;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

  }
}
```

I'm using this with docker containers. The compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3"
networks:
  nextcloudpi:

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx
    image: cptdaydreamer/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 4443:4443
      - 6800:6800
    volumes:
      - /media/storage/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live:/etc/letsencrypt/live
      - /etc/letsencrypt/archive:/etc/letsencrypt/archive
    links:
      - wordpress
    depends_on:
      - nextcloudpi
    networks:
      - nextcloudpi
      - default
  nextcloudpi:
    restart: always
    container_name: nextcloudpi
    image: cptdaydreamer/nextcloudpi:latest
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
      - 4443
      - 6800
    volumes:
     - /media/storage/data:/data
     - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    networks:
      - nextcloudpi

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9001:9000
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /media/storage/portainer:/data
    container_name: portainer

  db:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb:latest
    #ports:
    #  - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /media/storage/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $PRIVATE
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $PRIVATE
      MYSQL_USER: $PRIVATE
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $PRIVATE

  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    links:
      - db
    #ports:
    #  - 9000:9000
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    expose:
      - "80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /media/storage/wordpress:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      #WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: $PRIVATE
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: $PRIVATE
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: $PRIVATE
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: $PRIVATE
```

I don't know what the exact problem is. The logs of the docker container of wordpress shows:

```
[15-Mar-2020 00:50:24] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[15-Mar-2020 00:50:24] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

Any ideas?

Updated on request:

- Wordpress image is now latest instead of 7.3-fpm
- Current used nginx.conf

Answer (score 2):

Try edit to `wordpress:9000` in the proxy pass script and change the Nginx config to this.

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

There's a mistake in your understanding. The `wordpress-php-fpm` image just expose the PHP-FPM service at port 9000, nothing running at `https://wordpress:443` so Nginx will throw the 502 status. That's why you should use the `fastcgi_pass` to connect to PHP-FPM instead of `proxy_pass` like NextCloud API expose the https at port 4443 already.

---

When you split your stacks to 2 docker-compose.yml, everything will become more clearly and seperately.

```
-- wordpress/
--- docker-compose.yml
--- data/

-- nextcloud/
--- docker-compose.yml
--- data/
```

This is how Docker works.

From my experience, when using Docker, just keep a stack standalone. I mean Nextcloud going with an database, good. Then make another stack with WordPess and another database instance. It's take all the advantage of Docker and seperate the application each other.

Comment: Would not be possible as I know to configure an upstream because it's getting the internal docker container IP of wordpress. I've tried to configure an upstream but that didn't worked. And I never divided docker container into stacks. I would have to read about it, how it works.

Comment: I had the configuration exactly like you wrote it. Still there was error 502. I was now only able to get it run with the wordpress:latest image and without https in my config. But the docker-compose attempt sounds interesting. Didn't even know that I can run multiple compose files. But I don't know what should become more clearly then. As well where should I have my nginx container then because wordpress and nextcloud need it.

Comment: Updated my current config